# Insertar mas de 2 checkbox en un solo campo de SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hola Buen dia tengo un formulario el cual tengo mas de un checkbox y al momento de seleccionar 1 o varios para guardar en la base de datos los inserta si, pero los inserta por separado y me gustaria saber como los puedo insertar juntos en un solo campo en este caso en el de inventario.

(Codigo de mi formulario donde se mostrara para seleccionar los checkbox)

```
 <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Inventario:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="ANTENA">ANTENA <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="ESPEJO LATERAL">ESPEJO LATERAL <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="EMBLEMAS">EMBLEMAS <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="TAPONES RUEDAS(4)">TAPONES RUEDAS(4) <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="MOLDURAS">MOLDURAS COMPLETAS<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="TAPÓN DE GASOLINA">TAPÓN DE GASOLINA<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="LLANTA DE REFACCIÓN">LLANATA DE REFACCIÓN<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="RADIO/TIPO">RADIO/TIPO<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="ENCENDEDOR">ENCENDEDOR<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="TAPETES">TAPETES<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="BOCINA DE CLAXÓN">BOCINA DE CLAXON<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA">GOLPES EN CARROCERÍA<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="EXTINTOR">EXTINTOR<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="TARJETA DE GASOLINA">TARJETA DE GASOLINA<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="GATO">GATO<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="LLAVE DE RUEDAS">LLAVE DE RUEDAS<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS">ESTUCHE DE HERRAMIENTAS<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD">TRIÁNGULOS DE SEGURIDAD<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN">CERTIFICADO DE VERIFICACIÓN<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN">TARJETA DE CIRCULACIÓN<br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

(Codigo donde se ingresa el INSERT INTO para la tabla en la base de datos)

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
```

$fecha=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if($action == 'orden'){

```
$nombre= UPPER($_POST['nombre']); 
$direccion= $_POST['direccion']; 
$VIN = $_POST['VIN']; 
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$marca = $_POST['marca']; 
$modelo= $_POST['modelo']; 
$año = $_POST['año'];
$kilometraje = $_POST['kilometraje']; 
$placas = $_POST['placas']; 
$color = $_POST['color']; 
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; 
$comentarios = $_POST['comentarios']; 
foreach ($checkbox as $llave => $valor)
if($query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO orden_entrada (nombre,direccion,VIN,telefono,marca,modelo,año,kilometraje,placas,color,inventario,comentarios,fecha)
                                    VALUES
                                    ('$nombre','$direccion','$VIN','$telefono','$marca','$modelo','$año','$kilometraje','$placas','$color','$valor','$comentarios',
                                    '$fecha')")){
include '../includes/msg_box.php';
```

}else{
echo "alert('¡Error al guardar, debe introduccir todos los datos requeridos!.')";
}
}

¿Que podria hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(ejemplo de lo que busco hacer)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código como texto y no como imagen por favor

Comment: listo ya lo hice

Comment: No me quedo muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Al momento de seleccionar 2 checkbox, quieres enviar su valor a una columna que tienes en tu base de datos?

Comment: si por ejemplo si yo selecciono mas de 1 opcion que esas opciones se guarden en un solo campo de la base de datos (en donde dice inventario) no por separado como se muestra en la imagen

Comment: Intenta usar la función `isset()` para verificar si cada checkbox ha sido seleccionado o no. Y luego intenta convertir ese array de checkboxs en una cadena separada por comas, así es como lo haría yo

Comment: Ya subi una imagen de que es lo que busco para que mas o menos se perciba que es lo que quiero

Comment: no por favor no... como lo estas haciendo, aunque no es del todo correcto, porque no esta normalizado, es mil veces mejor que lo que queres hacer... En realidad, todos esos checkbox deberian estar en otra table.. lee sobre normalizacion de bases de datos...

Comment: Muchas gracias por corregirme -gbianchi pero este es una practica solamente y me gustaria intentar lo que busco solamente

Answer (score 0):

Guárdalo como JSON usando `json_encode`

```
$nombre= UPPER($_POST['nombre']); 
$direccion= $_POST['direccion']; 
$VIN = $_POST['VIN']; 
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$marca = $_POST['marca']; 
$modelo= $_POST['modelo']; 
$año = $_POST['año'];
$kilometraje = $_POST['kilometraje']; 
$placas = $_POST['placas']; 
$color = $_POST['color']; 
$checkbox = json_encode($_POST['checkbox']); // <-aca 
$comentarios = $_POST['comentarios']; 
if($query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO orden_entrada (nombre,direccion,VIN,telefono,marca,modelo,año,kilometraje,placas,color,inventario,comentarios,fecha)
                                    VALUES
                                    ('$nombre','$direccion','$VIN','$telefono','$marca','$modelo','$año','$kilometraje','$placas','$color','$checkbox','$comentarios',
                                    '$fecha')")){
```

Y obviamente para leer el valor haces lo inverso con `json_decode`

**¿Por qué JSON?**

Porque si vas a seguir el camino de guardar una lista en una misma celda, es mejor hacerlo con un formato establecido y no usar un separador arbitrario como lo puede ser una coma.

- Puedes convertir el objeto de manera simple usando `json_encode` y `json_decode`
- En último caso puedes realizar consultas en él usando `JSON_VALUE` ([más información](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16))

Comment: Muchas gracias @YUSSEF me fue de gran ayuda tu aportacion te lo agradezco mucho